# Time Varying Potential, series solution

Tags: quantum-mechanics, schroedinger-equation, wavefunction, perturbation-theory

Suppose we have a time varying potential $$\left( -\frac{1}{2m}\nabla^2+ V(\vec{r},t)\right)\psi = i\partial_t \psi$$ then I want to know why is the general solution written as $\psi = \displaystyle\sum_n a_n(t)\phi_n(\vec{r})e^{-iE_n t} $ Particularly, why do we get a time dependent coefficient $a_n(t)$. This confuses me because when we have a time independent potential, then we use variable separation and usual method to get the general solution $$\psi = \displaystyle\sum_n a_n\phi_n(\vec{r})e^{-iE_n t}$$ However, the time varying counterpart cannot be reduced this way by variable seperation.

EDIT:
I could not find a free preview of the book I am using, however, the [lectures here](http://galileo.phys.virginia.edu/classes/752.mf1i.spring03/Time_Dep_PT.htm) for example, use the same solution.

Comment: Are you sure there is $\phi_n(t)\exp(-iE_nt)$ not just $\phi_n\exp(-iE_nt)$?

Comment: @MaksimZholudev That was a typo. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 2):

The basis functions $\phi_n(\vec{r})$ and the energies $E_n$ are the solutions of the stationary Schrödinger equation:
$$
\left( -\frac{1}{2m}\nabla^2+ V_0(\vec{r})\right)\phi_n(\vec{r}) = E_n \phi_n(\vec{r})
$$
If the Hamiltonian depends on time one even can not write this equation.
But the set of functions $\phi_n(\vec{r})$ is a full basis in the Hilbert space.
So one always can expand **any** function (from this space) over this basis.

The snapshot of the wavefunction $\psi(\vec{r},t)$ at the moment $t$ is just a function of coordinates and the element of this Hilbert space. So we can expand it:
$$
\psi(\vec{r},t) = \sum_n b_n(t) \phi_n(\vec{r})
$$
If the Hamiltonian do not depend on time the expansion coefficients can be easily derived from the general Schrödinger equation (the one with the time derivative):
$$
b_n(t) = a^{(0)}_n e^{-iE_nt}
$$

In the case of time-dependent potential these coefficients are usually considered as unknown functions of time:
$$
b_n(t) = a_n(t) e^{-iE_nt}
$$

The perturbation theory is used to find the approximation for these functions.

Answer (score 2):

1) What OP is looking at is known as time-dependent [perturbation theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perturbation_theory_%28quantum_mechanics%29). Here the energies $E_n$ are eigenvalues for the unperturbed time-independent Hamiltonian $H^{(0)}$. The full Hamiltonian is

$$H(t)~=~H^{(0)}+V(t).$$

2) Imagine for a second that the potential $V$ is time-independent and commutes with $H^{(0)}$. Let $v_n$ be the eigenvalues of $V$. In the time independent case, the wavefunction solution is then of the form

$$\psi(t,\vec{r}) ~=~ \displaystyle\sum_n c_n\phi_n(\vec{r})e^{-i(E_n+v_n) t}
~=~ \displaystyle\sum_n \left(c_n e^{-iv_nt}\right) \phi_n(\vec{r})e^{-iE_n t}.$$

3) For general time-dependent perturbations $V(t)$, it is hence natural to expect that the coefficients $a_n(t)$ in the [eigenfunction expansion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%E2%80%93Schmidt_theorem)

$$\psi(t,\vec{r})  ~=~ \displaystyle\sum_n a_n(t)\phi_n(\vec{r})e^{-iE_n t} $$

could depend on time $t$, cf. OP's question(v2). Here $\phi_n(\vec{r})$ denote eigenfunctions for the unperturbed problem,

$$ H^{(0)}\phi_n(\vec{r})~=~E_n\phi_n(\vec{r}).$$

Answer (score 0):

It is simply a matter of definition. If the time-dependent coefficients can be reasonably found from the Scroedinger equation, then it is a solution for your time-dependent wave function. It is introducing new variables $a_n (t)$ and determining them from the exact equation. It can always be done.